# Use MetadatacontainerID in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, tooling-api

I have written a code for creation of MetadataContainer in Tooling API in my Apex class.

```
public Static void createNewMetadataContainer() {
    ToolingApi tooling = new ToolingApi();
    string yourContainerName = 'ABCContainer';
    List<ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer> containers = (List<ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer>) tooling.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM MetadataContainer WHERE Name = \''+yourContainerName+'\'').records;

    if(containers!=null &&  containers.size()>0) {
        tooling.deleteSObject(ToolingAPI.SObjectType.MetadataContainer, containers[0].Id);
    }

    ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer container = new ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer();
    container.name = yourContainerName;
    ToolingAPI.SaveResult containerSaveResult = tooling.createSObject(container);
    Id containerId = containerSaveResult.id;
    System.debug('+++++++++++++'+containerID);
    //return containerId;
}
```

Now if I need to display or use this container ID in my Visualforce page using this class as an extension, how can I do so?

I have tried changing the method signature to public Static Id getNewMetadataContainer() and return value to containerID and tried to display containerID in Visualforce using `apex:outputText value="{!NewMetadataContainer}"` but this shows

> ToolingAPI error

Comment: Where is the message "ToolingAPI error" coming from? Seems like it would be something from the wrapper code. What does the Apex Debug log show is going on?

Comment: The error is resolved. It turns out, the endpoint was not correctly being provided.